# add an id key to an integer from a POST

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

So i got a form that has 2 fields like:

```
name="capability_list[name]"
name="capability_list[desc]"
```

on my processing page i have something like:

```
$values[] = $_POST['capability_list']
update_option( 'my_key', $values );
```

I want to add another id field to the array of each form post that will be incremental.
So for example on first post submit i will have :

```
name='test1', desc='desc1', id='1'
```

The next form submit will get the id='2' and so on.

But the second time i do an entry it has to know that there is an id='1' and add 2. Same if i delete in the future the entry with id='2' the next one i add has to go to '3' and not 2.

Edit:
just like on a database table you have a field ID which is auto incremented on each table entry

Comment: where is this ID coming from? a database? it is NORMAL for ids to not get re-used, and generally a very bad idea to try and re-use IDs in the first place.

Comment: the id can come from nowhere and i could add it in the processing page. I just need a way to track each array entry easier by ID

Comment: something like $values['id']= $i++

Comment: and like I said, where will this ID come from? every http request is independent of every other one, and every PHP invocation basically starts "from scratch". you can easily set $i=1 and increment it in your script, but once the script exits, $i is destroyed and the value lost.

Comment: i`m not sure where the ID should come from. Could be generated on the spot. but it has to know what value to take next on each entry